# como puedo hacer consultas negativas en php

Tags: php, mysql

Mi intención es seleccionar todos los usuarios que no tengan cierto id en el campo 'de'.

Ejemplo: quiero seleccionar a todos los usuarios que no estén siendo seguidos por otro usuario para mostrárselos y que se puedan seguir.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE not in de = '".$_SESSION['id_use']."' ");

$columna = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

Comment: Creo que podría ser conveniente que pongas el diseño de la base de datos que tienes.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: ¿Y el error? ¿El contexto? ¿Podrías retroalimentar tu pregunta? Como por ejemplo, tu ER, etc

Answer (score 0):

¿A esto es lo que te refiriendo? lo distinto, para eso se usa != o <>

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE de != '".$_SESSION['id_use']."' ");

$columna = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

Comment: Podrias definir que contiene la variable 'id_use' es una dato unico o es un arreglo de muchos valores?

Answer (score 0):

Para comenzar, el where de tu consulta debe ser de la siguiente forma:

```
$idUse = $_SESSION['id_use'];

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM amigos WHERE de not in ('".$idUse.")' ");

$columna = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
```

si tu variable de sesion `$_SESSION['id_use']` es un arreglo sera necesario reccorerla, concatenar los valores y asignarlos a $idUse, si tu variable es un solo valor escalar entonces lo mejor seria usar el operador de comparacion <> (diferente de) o !=.

Ya con esas modifaciones no deberas tener problemas con tu consulta.

Espero sea de utilidad

Saludos

Comment: Si es un array puedes utilizar implode para crear una cadena con los elementos separados por , y agregarlo directamente en el IN de la consulta